# Getting properties of derived object from base object list

Tags: c#, generics, collections, abstract

I'm looking for simple way to get properties from my derived class, which inherit abstract class.

My code:

```
public abstract class PointLayer
{
    public abstract Type Type { get;}
}
public class PointLayer<T> : PointLayer
{
    #region PROPERTIES
    public override Type Type { get; }
    public string MapName { get; private set; }
    public MapType MapType { get; private set; }
    public Point<T> Point { get; private set; }
    #endregion

    #region C'TOR
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor creating PointLayer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mapName">Map name</param>
    /// <param name="mapType">Map type</param>
    /// <param name="point">Point</param>
    public PointLayer(string mapName, MapType mapType, Point<T> point)
    {
        MapName = mapName;
        Point = point;
        MapType = mapType;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And I try to get i.e. MapName from elements of Layers list.

```
Layers = new List<PointLayer>();
```

Comment: What is the actual usage? Why not move `MapName` to base class?

Comment: Because I need Layers list, which contains Layer<T> different types.

Comment: Do you mean something like `var  allLayers = List<PointLayer<string>>();` do something with the list and later on `allLayers.Select(pl => pl. MapName);`

Comment: Ok, but then I've got list of PointLayer<string>, I need to have i.e. first element PointLayer<double>, but second PointLayer<int> :)

Comment: What did you want to do with your point? Just printing it to console or do some math?

Comment: I need points to calculate smth and store their values, and coordinates.

Comment: I use it to some kind of map, which has few different layers.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but for me it seems to be easier for you to convert your `PointLayer<T>` to some handy `PointLayer<double>` or to a simple Point within your base class and then calculate.

Answer (score 0):

In `Layers = new List<PointLayer>();`

Layers is a list of the parent class. You can't access child properties from the parent class, as you have no guarantee that an object of type PointLayer has property MapName.

If you are sure the objects are actually of type PointLayer you can cast them:

```
    var GenericLayers = new List<PointLayer<int>>();
    List<PointLayer> Layers = GenericLayers.Select(x => (PointLayer)x).ToList();

    List<int> MapNames = Layers.Select(x => ((PointLayer<int>)x).MapName).ToList();
```

EDIT:

Given your answer that you want a list of different types of PointLayer you should simply use a list of PointLayer:

```
public abstract class PointLayer
{
    public abstract Type Type { get;}
    public abstract string MapName { get; protected set; }
    public abstract MapType MapType { get; protected set; }
    public abstract Point Point { get; protected set; }
}
public class PointLayer<T> : PointLayer
{
    #region PROPERTIES
    public override Type Type { get; }
    public override string MapName { get; protected set; }
    public override MapType MapType { get; protected set; }
    public override Point Point { get; protected set; }
    #endregion

    #region C'TOR
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor creating PointLayer
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mapName">Map name</param>
    /// <param name="mapType">Map type</param>
    /// <param name="point">Point</param>
    public PointLayer(string mapName, MapType mapType, Point<T> point)
    {
        Type=typeof(T);
        MapName = mapName;
        Point = point;
        MapType = mapType;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Then

```
Layers = new List<PointLayer>();
var MapNames=Layers.Select(x=>x.MapName);
```

Inherit `Point<T>` from `point`and I think this is the best you can do. Depending on what functionality `Point<T>` has over `Point`, this may be sufficient. Although you will not be able to tell what is the type parameter of point, since you only know this at runtime there is no way around this. If `Point` is abstract, and has all the methods included in `Point<T>` very little difference will be made.

Comment: Thank you, but the next problem is Point<T> in base class. To have property of T type, class has to be T type too.